# Reading id value from html ionic

Tags: ionic3

Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

this is the code

list.html:

```
enter code<ion-list>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let result of seznamNaprav">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left>
            <img [src]="result.src">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <button  [id]="result.id" ion-button clear (click)="buttonOgled($event)" [innerText] = "result.name"></button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list> here
```

list.ts

```
buttonOgled($event){

  let id = event.currentTarget as HTMLButtonElement;

  let data = {id: event.target.id }; //in the variable we save the ID value of the exercise that we have selected

  console.log(data.id); //checking the passing ID

  this.navCtrl.push(NapravaPage, data); //we push the data to the next page

  // this.navCtrl.push(NapravaPage);
```

}

when I first run the app the mentioned error appear. But after I save again my project, without changing anything the error disappear. Until I test the code in the browser, there is no problem, but launching it on a real device doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<button  [id]="result.id" ion-button clear (click)="buttonOgled($event)" [innerText] = "result.name"></button>
```

To this

```
<button ion-button clear (click)="buttonOgled(result.id)" [innerText] = "result.name"></button>
```

Then in list .ts it you can just redirect:

```
buttonOgled(id) {
this.navCtrl.push(NapravaPage,{ id: id });
}
```